# Is this possible to extract wanted part in url with java?

Tags: java, regex, url, pattern-matching

```
url:
/apiary/grm/v2dfa/aaa/b/234    => aaa/b/234 
/apiary/grm/v2erqer/fs/ccc/342 => fs/ccc/342
/apiary/grm/v4dfs/dfa/         => dfa
/apiary/batch                  => /apiary/batch
```

requirement:

1.from right to left, extract whatever after pattern v\d+[^/]+
2.remove starting and ending / from we get in 1.

It is easy to use string strategy, but I was wondering if this is possible with pure regex for once, since regex matches something but this requirement ask you to match something after matching pattern.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You can make use of String methods.. and it's up to you to build your strategy

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree it is a pure code-writing request, since I see you have already written the regex yourself: `v\d+[^/]+`. It matches `v` followed by 1 or more digits and then 1 or more characters other than `/`.

What I suggest is using a `replaceAll` with a bit modified regex:

```
.replaceAll("^.*/v\\d[^/]*/(.*?)/?$", "$1")
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/bFgrv1)

I added:

- `^` - beginning of string
- `.*/` - match 0 or more characters from the beginning up to na dincluding `/`
- `v\\d` - `v` and a digit
- `[^/]*/` - and then 0 or more characters other than `/` and then a literal `/`
- `(.*?)` - match and capture into Group 1 zero or more any characters but a newline, as few as possible (so as not to capture the last `/`)
- `/?$` - up to the end of string with an optional `/` at the end.